# Sending email to multiple recipients in Exchange Server 2007

Tags: email, exchange

How can I accomplish the following:

There are several general purpose addresses

- support@mycompany.com
- orders@mycompany.com
- Sales@mycompany.com

Currently messages to these addresses are set to forward to specific user accounts for example:

- support@mycompany.com forwards to user1@mycompany.com
- orders@mycompnay.com forwards to user2@mycompnay.com and
- sales@mycompany.com forwards to user3@mycompany.com

However I would like to set up the system so that the following is true:

- support@mycompany.com forwards to user1@mycompany.com, user4@mycompany.com and user6@mycompany.com
- orders@mycompany.com forwards to user2@mycompany.com  and user5@mycompany.com
- sales@mycompany.com forwards to user3@mycompany.com, user7@mycompany.com and user8@mycompany.com

I tried adding the general purpose accounts to the outlook clients of the specific users however the software tells me that only 1 exchange account can be added per profile.

I do not want my users to have to switch between profiles just to check the general purpose accounts and I do not want users to pull the general purpose account messages down using POP because there may be issues when a user processes messages and other users in his or her team cannot tell what messages need to be processed.

Can someone help point me in the right direction for configuring our exchange server to allow these general purpose addresses to deliver messages to multiple users for processing?

Comment: 1. If you're running Exchange then your users shouldn't be using POP to retrieve their email. If they are, you're doing it wrong.

2. Create Distribution Groups for these email addresses and add the appropriate users to these groups.

3. Done.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their help with this! I ended up going the route of making shared mailboxes for the department addresses, adding users to security groups with fullpermission and send-as access to the department mailboxes and then adding the department mailbox to the users' outlook profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two main ways that you can look at doing this.

1) As Joe mentioned in his comment, you can create distribution groups for the primary address and add the users you want members of the group. This will deliver any messages sent to the primary address to the members mailbox.

2) You can create an Active Directory account for each primary address and create a mailbox for the account. Create security groups as needed and assign the group full permission to the mailboxes. Assign users to the appropriate security groups. From Outlook, you can add the mailbox to their existing profile using the More Settings/Advanced/Open these additional mailboxes (this location may be different depending on the version of Outlook). This will allow those users access to the mailbox.

The two options are similar, but differ in subtle ways. They also have slightly different ways of doing a reply as the primary mailbox account as opposed to the individual user accounts when replying to messages sent to the primary/shared address.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

One is to use distribution lists. Each user will receive the message in to their own mailbox. This has the obvious downside that if another user processes the message and deletes/files it then no one else will know because they have their own copy of the message.

The other is to use a shared mailbox. Create the mailbox just like any other user. Then give the users that need to monitor the email full access to the mailbox. How you do that is dependent on the version of Exchange you're running. With Exchange 2010 and later with Outlook 2010 or later, the mailbox will automatically show up in Outlook with no additional configuration. Otherwise you add access to the mailbox through the existing Exchange account configuration on Outlook, not by adding another account. See http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/show/how-to-add-another-persons-mailbox-to-your-outlook-2010-profile-exchange-2007 for step-by-step instructions.

Comment: And, while frowned upon nowadays since MS keeps saying they will go away...you could use Public Folders as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this

1. Create distribution lists for support@, orders@ etc. and add the users to those list.  That way they will receive the emails.
2. Within the profile for the Exchange user, go to the More settings -> Advanced and add them to the "Open these additional mailboxes"

You don't say whether you want to be able to send as userX@ or orders@ etc.   You may wish to clarify by updating your questions